# How to add a variant of a pivot to look left twice?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to add to the script written by Tradingview another variant (lbL=10) so that it can look left 2 times (5 bars left "lbL=5" and 10 bars left "lbL=10")

Do you know if it's possible?
Thanks

```
lbR = 5
lbL = 5
rangeUpper = 60
rangeLower = 5

plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper
    
// Regular Bullish   
oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
priceLL = close[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, close[lbR], 1)
bullCond = priceLL and oscHL and plFound
plot(plFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? col_green : na)

// Regular Bearish
oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])
priceHH = close[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, close[lbR], 1)
bearCond = priceHH and oscLH and phFound
plot(phFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bearish', linewidth=2, color=bearCond ? col_red : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another variable and call another `ta.pivothigh()` and `ta.pivotlow()` based on that.

```
lbR = 5
lbL = 5
lbL_2 = 10

plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

plFound_2 = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL_2, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound_2 = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL_2, lbR)) ? false : true
```

However, I believe you only need to find a pivot with the highest lookback value. If the current bar is a pivot of the last 10 bars, it is also a pivot of the last 5 bars too.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I also need to add oscHL_2, priceLL_2 and bullCond_2 with plFound_2 inside?